# In Angular how to use comma for digits (only two) and comma for number?

Tags: angular

I have to format a number with two decimal and with italian format like:

> 1.111.111,00

I have this input with two way bindings:

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="praticaSelezionata.Importo | number:'1.2-2':'it-IT'"
    (ngModelChange)="praticaSelezionata.Importo=$event" formControlName="importo"
    [disabled]="formDisabilitato"
    class="input-sm form-control mr-sm-4 inputRightFormat mb-sm-1"
    style="height:34px;width:40%;margin-right:3px !important" id="importo" disabled>
```

in `app.module.ts` I have set:

```
import localeIt from '@angular/common/locales/it';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

registerLocaleData(localeIt);

providers:[{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it-IT'}...
```

but when I digit inside input field I receive this error

```
InvalidPipeArgument: '10,13 is not a number' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'
```

and

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined: 10.1311'. Current value: 'undefined: 10,13'
```

and a warning

```
The specified value "10,13" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

I'm new in angular, can you help me?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value `praticaSelezionata.Importo` is a string with the value "10,13". This is a not a number. You can do a couple of things:

Change the way the data gets obtained. I'm suspecting some API. This needs to return `10.13`, not `"10,13"`.

Parse the value after you receive the data to make string comma numbers into normal numbers.

Use a pipe in front of your number pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'stringNr'
})
export class StringNrPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(stringNr: string | number): number {
    if (typeof stringNr === 'string') {
      return Number.parseFloat(stringNr.replace(',', '.')) || 0
    }

    return stringNr || 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a String for the binding? because the interface has  Importo: number;
The API return Importo: 10.1311 by JSON

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, error and not two digits. Futhermore sometimes call the pipe and sometimes no(on the startup call the pipe even if should not)